# L'etimo antico del genio: cosa significa?

Tags: meaning

Il telegiornale di oggi ha dato la notizia della morte del grande cuoco Gualtiero Marchesi.

Nel servizio è stato riproposto un frammento di un'intervista in cui Marchesi declamava una massima a proposito dell'arte della cucina: "Creare è fare!".

A seguito di tale massima, Marchesi ha confidato al giornalista qualcosa che assomigliava a: "Etimo dell'antico genio..."

Mi sfugge il significato di questo frammento di frase. Cosa vuol dire essere *etimo dell'antico genio*?

Answer (score 5):

Il riferimento è all'etimo del verbo **creare** nella sua accezione di **fare**.

La derivazione più attendibile è infatti dal sanscrito *kar-*, che ritroviamo nel greco κραίνω *kraino* («produco»), oltre che in κράντωρ *krantor* (il «dominatore») e κρείων *kreion* («colui che fa»), sempre col significato di «**produrre**», «**generare**», «**fabbricare**».

La presenza della radice sanscrita nel nome di due divinità — Κρόνος *Kronos* (il «creatore»), padre di Zeus, e **Ceres** («quella che produce»), divinità romana delle messi, confermerebbe il fatto che la **capacità di creare**, la **creatività**, *rappresenta una forma specifica del fare*. La concezione cristiana del Dio «creatore» ribadisce ulteriormente la *funzione «**generativa**» della creazione*.

Il mondo greco antico conosce due termini per l'intelligenza:

- νοῦς **nous**: l’intelligenza inattiva e contemplativa, astratta, disimpegnata dal «fare».
- μῆτις **metis**: l’intelligenza attiva ed esecutrice, preposta all’azione.

**Il nous contempla. La metis, come la creatività, genera.** Odisseo e Prometeo sono esempi della metis.

Connesso alla *metis* è il καιρός **kairos**, il tempo opportuno, l’attimo che fugge, e cioè quella variante qualitativa del tempo in cui si manifesta un evento extra-ordinario, che va afferrato al volo.

Nella cultura moderna e contemporanea, soprattutto nella concezione romantica, *la creatività è un requisito attinente all’affettività e ai sentimenti*, ma non alla ragione.

Dai primi decenni del Novecento, però, non l’arte, ma *la scienza*, non gli affetti ma *la razionalità, costituiscono il terreno di espressione della creatività*.

Si profila con ciò una sorta di dualismo di creazione nell'ambito artistico, in una visione in sostanza antirazionalistica, e di creazione di genio in campo scientifico, capace di produrre innovazione anche in campo tecnologico.

In questo senso l'articolo argomenta il concetto che la creatività affonda le sue radici del genio nell'etimo antico.

Qui trovi [l'articolo completo](https://www.micciacorta.it/2013/08/2013-08-30-07-06-00/) ([disponibile anche in pdf](http://e-mindset.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Creare-significa-fare.pdf)).

Per altri riferimenti sull'etimologia puoi vedere anche qui la voce [creare](http://www.etimo.it/?term=creare).

Comment: Le risposte consistenti in soltanto un link sono in genere considerate inadeguate su StackExchange. Potresti riassumere il contenuto dell'articolo?

Comment: @Charo sì certo, hai ragione.

Comment: Che creare fosse parte dell'etimologia del verbo fare mi era chiaro. Questo articolo chiarisce perché si parli di genio, tuttavia qui si parla di etimo di creare, non di etimo del genio. A meno che con genio non si intenda colui che genera. C'è di mezzo, per caso, una qualche figura retorica?

Comment: @Zachiel A dire il vero io non ho visto nessun chiarimento su "genio". Quello che ho inteso io è che si parla dell'attività creatrice del genio (di cui non viene fornita nessuna definizione) e questo "creare" ha una radice profonda nel passato, un etimo antico.